# Blocking form sending by ip after 3 uses

Tags: javascript, html, database, spam-prevention

I need to build a landing page with a form,
and the client is afraid of getting spammed, so I want to block
an ip from sending after three times, with javascript. Is it possible?
I don't know MySql and php so well.

If it is not possible, please give me a way to make it work in another way.

If you want, you can also upvote, because right now I'm blocked from posting questions.

Comment: Blocking based on IP is not reliable, IP addresses change and are shared.

Comment: What do you mean in "change and shared"?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do something like that with JavaScript (in the browser). That needs to be done at the server.

Comment: Can you point me to a specific article on the topic please?

Comment: You cannot rely on one visitor having one IP addres. Yes, Javascript is unsuitable to block people. So are cookies or webstorage. Use something on the server or use a CAPTCHA.

Comment: you have clients for this? :O

Comment: Cliens for what?

Comment: @LaviArzi The facts are ANYBODY can bypass javascript. And bots will bypass javascript. And IP Addresses are shared. If you more than one device in your home your entire house shares an IP. If you access from college or work your entire campus/office may share an IP address.

Comment: @LaviArzi Additionally, if you are trying to  block spam the easiest way is a honeypot on the server. Render a specific input field, use roundabout css tricks to hide the field, and if that field is filled in, assume a bot submitted the form and just dont save it or send it.

Comment: @Marie Indeed, a honeypot still catches most spam bots, they are not very clever.

Answer (score 0):

Without any backend support, there is not much to do. What you can try to use, is to store information in

- cookies
- webstorage (browser feature: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

In that case you will have some possiblity to block the same user (while using the same browser on one machine).

Comment: But bots aren't using cookies, so it won't be practical.

Comment: Ahh, you are right... Then captcha : maybe someting like this: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html

Answer (score 0):

What you'r trying to do is get the client address like this with php:

```
function getUserIpAddr(){
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
        //ip from share internet
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
        //ip pass from proxy
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

and store it in mysql.
There is no working unexploitable js code wich you could use for blocking. Cookies and webstorage can store information but only on the pc and only in the same webbrowser if the client has it enabled. So no safe way with JS.

Comment: So Is there another way for doing it, blocking by MAC, I don't know.

Comment: The problem is where you'r storing this information not how you retrive it. ReCaptcha is your only safe way.